# UWP binding to a method inside a ListView

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

How do you call a custom method in a bind that already has a x:DataType set to a class?  The error message shows: **The property 'TotalMembers' was not found in type 'Family'.**  When adding the method from the page load to the Family class, the error remains.

```
// model
public class Family
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int TotalMembers() { return "some code..." }
}
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FamilyID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

// page load
public ObservableCollection<Family> ocFamily { get; set; }
ocFamily = new ObservableCollection<Family>();

// xaml
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ocFamily}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Family>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Surname}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind TotalMembers()}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The second textblock should show the total number of members of the family.

Comment: Should I be using a converter?

Comment: What build version of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: Min Version: Windows 10.0; Build 10586, Target Version: Windows 10 Anniversary Edition 10.0; 14393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To use functions with {x:Bind}, your app's minimum target SDK version
>   must be 14393 or later. You can't use functions when your app targets
>   earlier versions of Windows 10.

You will need to set the *Min Version* to at least *14393* for *x:Bind to function* to work.

You can read more from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension).

In your case, you should be able to create a `TotalMembers` *property* instead of a *method*.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing this wrong.  I need to call a function in the app that queries the database and shows the dynamic row count of family members for the second table.  This wouldn't be a property in the family table, as rows get added in the Person table, the count would change in the binded listview.

Comment: The problem is the DataTemplate is already bound to the class for the listview.

Comment: I am a bit confused but why not create a property that wraps the method?

Comment: That does work, but I can't pass a parameter into a property for more complex code.

Comment: @detailCode I see, in that case you can try with a Converter.